# api-key not found in browser (404)

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a news application using angular and ionic4. I have put my api url and api key in the environment.ts file as below:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl:'https://n------',
  apiKey:'api-key----'
};
```

my news.service.ts file is as:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
    
    const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;
    const API_KEY = environment.apiKey;
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class NewsService {
    
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
    
      getData(url){
        return this.http.get('${API_URL}/${url}&apiKey=${API_KEY}');
      }
    }
```

However, when I refresh the browser it shows the below error:

[image]

Comment: Did it solve your problem ? If the answer helped, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to interpolate variable in the string you pass to http.get. To do so, you have to use backtick (like that: ` ) instead of tick. Give it a try and let me know.